# Weird behaivior of ProgressBar in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, progress-bar

So, I'm tryging to use a progress bar in my WP7 Panorama aplication.
There is one page, that is downloadidng data from the web, so I want to indicate that my App is doing something with ProgressBar

```
<controls:PanoramaItem Header="news">
            <Popup Name="myWeatherPopup" IsOpen="False" Width="404" Height="Auto" Margin="0,136,4,293">
                <StackPanel>

                    <ProgressBar Height="Auto" IsIndeterminate="True" Width="400" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Loading" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Gray" />

                </StackPanel>
            </Popup>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>
```

It basically works as it should. However, there is one tiny (and anoying bug).
The first... run (?) of the dots appears on every panorama item, just under header. After that, it returns on its normal position under news item.

The same thing happens on emulator and Lumia 800.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfoqb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried without the Popup, by just setting the Visibility property on the StackPanel?